# Javascript quiz answers with key input not mouse click

Tags: javascript, html, input, keyboard

For a project Im making a quiz with HTML and Javascript. Problem is that I have to choose the answers A B C with my mouse. I want to choose these anwsers by linking it to a key press. I am using a makey makey, because it needs to be interactive. A makey makey has key inputs like W A S D F G

So Short summary: anwser A B or C linked to W A or S (or a other key input).

This way I dont have to use my mouse, but only a simple key button.

Comment: document.body.onkeyup

Comment: any test written in JS is going to be easy to cheat on

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.onkeyup = function(event){
    var tKey = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (tKey === 87) console.log('w')
    if (tKey === 65) console.log('a')
    if (tKey === 83) console.log('s')
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2379ju80/

http://www.mediaevent.de/javascript/Extras-Javascript-Keycodes.html

Edit: Question two.

You can do it the same way in which you are getting the pressed key.

```
// Wat een click / button-press doet
function answer(classe){
    //..
    //..
    //At the end of the function..
    if(currentQuestion === 10) //10 = max amount of questions = end of quiz (fill in your number instead)
        switch(points){
            case 0: //We reached 0 points
                alert('Do U even quiz bro???') //Display the message in the way you want. alert() is a quick try for that.
                break;
            case 20: //We reached 20 points in the quiz
                alert('Boo! U are bad') //Display the message in the way you want. alert() is a quick try for that.
                break;
            case 80: //We reached 80 points in the quiz
                alert('Congrats! U scored max.') //Display the message in the way you want. alert() is a quick try for that.
                break;
        }
}
```

Another solution if you want to display messages on flexible counts (points lower or bigger than)

```
// Wat een click / button-press doet
function answer(classe){
    //..
    //..
    //At the end of the function..
    if(currentQuestion === 10) //10 = max amount of questions = end of quiz (fill in your number instead){
        if (points >= 80) //We reached more than 79 points
            alert('Congrats! U scored max.') //Display the message in the way you want. alert() is a quick try for that.
        else if (points >= 20) //We reached more than 19 points
            alert('Boo! U are bad') //Display the message in the way you want. alert() is a quick try for that.
        else if (points < 20) //We reached less than 20 points
            alert('Do U even quiz bro???') //Display the message in the way you want. alert() is a quick try for that.
    }
}
```

Comment: @Pablo: Is there still help required on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I want to add now is an (I guess) if/else statement. That looks at the scored points from the quiz. At 80 points (for example): Congrats! U scored max. At 20 points: Boo! U are bad. This is the code I have now:

```js
// Hou de punten bij
var points = 0;

// Huidige vraag
var currentQuestion = 0;

// Bij klik -------------------------------------------------------------------
var answers = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

// Voeg een event handler click toe aan elke input (= knop)
for(i=0; i< answers.length; i++){
    answers[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Roep de answer-functie aan met de class van de knop als parameter
        var classe = this.className;
        answer(classe);
    });
}

// Bij toetsenbord ------------------------------------------------------------
// Luister naar toetsenbord-invoer
document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown);
function keyDown(key) {
    var keyCode = key.keyCode;

    switch(keyCode){
        case 65: // 65 = A
            // Roep de answer functie aan met de class van de knop die ook class first heeft (of second/third bij de volgende twee)
            answer(document.getElementsByClassName('show')[0].getElementsByClassName('first')[0].className);
            break;
        case 83: // 83 = S
            answer(document.getElementsByClassName('show')[0].getElementsByClassName('second')[0].className);
            break;
        case 68: // 68 = D
            answer(document.getElementsByClassName('show')[0].getElementsByClassName('third')[0].className);
            break;
        default: // voor als je per ongeluk de verkeerde knop indrukt
            console.log('je verklooit het hard');
    }
}

// Wat een click / button-press doet
function answer(classe){
    // Haal het stukje first/second/third uit de className (die worden gebruikt om onderscheid te maken tussen de knoppen bij toetsenbord invoer)
    var className = classe.substr(classe.indexOf(' ')+1);

    // Geef aantal punten als de class van de input one, two of threePoints is
    switch(className){
        case 'onePoint':
            points += 5;
            break;
        case 'twoPoints':
            points += 10;
            break;
        case 'threePoints':
            points += 20;
            break;
    }

    // Verberg de huidige vraag + toon de volgende
    document.getElementsByTagName('section')[currentQuestion].className = 'hide';
    document.getElementsByTagName('section')[currentQuestion + 1].className = 'show';

    currentQuestion++;

    // Als de laatste vraag is geweest, toon het eind scherm
    if(currentQuestion == document.getElementsByTagName('section').length - 1){
        document.getElementById('points').innerHTML += points;
        document.getElementById('end').className = 'show';
    }

}
```

```html
<section id="end" class="hide">
            <h1>Your choices are good for</h1>
            <p id="points">Punten: <p>
        </section>
```

I am an amateur with javascript. But If I could get this working I would be really greatfull.

Comment: Thank you so much man. Helped me a lot! Props II cant upvote you (too low score)

Comment: Just mark it as accepeted so others see the question as solved. No need to upvote.